# Game Scene is not getting updated

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

First of all I am new to game development and unity.

I was making a game menu with some buttons. There were 3 panels. Before running the game the camera was near 1st panel so i was able to see the 1st panel in game scene.

But when I moved the camera from 1st panel to 2nd one the game scene is not updating.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem.. Or are there anything I am missing..

Now I don't know what additional information should I share. Please mention those informations in comment below...

Thanx In Advance!!
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can we see the scene hierarchy, and also the positions of the camera when at the 1st panel and the 2nd? Right now there isn't a lot of concrete information to go off of in this question.

Comment: Updated with a screenshot :( @Serlite

Comment: And the camera preview is showing blank screen but when i run the app the screen has the 1st panel I mean the panel with 2buttons inside.. @Serlite

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: There is no code @Droppy

Comment: Then how is it a programming question and therefore on-topic for this site?

Comment: It's not its tags are related to unity @Droppy

Comment: Yes; programming questions related to unity.

Comment: I need help in unity so people who are familiar with can only help me @Droppy

Comment: SO do u know the solution of it? @Droppy

Comment: Nope; not a clue.  Ask on the Unity sites.

Comment: "But when I moved the camera from 1st panel to 2nd one the game scene is not updating." What do you mean by "not updating"? Is the camera preview keeps showing nothing?

Comment: The camera preview is always blank.. When i run the game the only screen i get is the 1st panel@zwcloud to be honest i think i am doing something wrong xD

Comment: @BuckyĎroid How are you moving the camera from the first to the second one? How have you implemented that?

Comment: changing the render mode to world space fixed the problem @Serlite But got another weird error https://youtu.be/r6m_RVFw7tA :(

Comment: Hmm, if you're facing a very different problem, you may want to flesh out a clear description and post a new question (also, a question with an upvoted answer isn't likely to get that much attention after an update).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011722/when-i-run-the-game-scene-on-unity-my-panels-dissappears @Serlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the UI to be rendered as an object in 3D space, the render mode of a canvas needs to be *World Space*.

[image: render mode: World Space]

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Canvas.html).

Comment: Please post a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011722/when-i-run-the-game-scene-on-unity-my-panels-dissappears