# When I run the game scene on unity my panels dissappears

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the error video

youtu.be/r6m_RVFw7tA

There is no code only panels and buttons.

If you need anything else then please comment..

Unity file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvxxjod1bs52u92/first.unity?dl=0

Comment: Please share your scene(the *.unity file) if possible.

Comment: Updated ....... @zwcloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *far clipping plane* of the camera is not far enough to cover the UI position. Set it to `3000`. If that doesn't work, bump it up more. far clipping plane of, `3000` seems to work fine in your case.

For perfect alignment of your camera, you need to reset its y-axis rotation to `0` then also change the x-axis position to be the position(`498`) of your canvas UI which is named **UI Container**. After this, you can then manually modify your UI component rotation/position to whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: Can i get the black layout theme on unity free version ? :(

Comment: No, you need the pro version for that. You can vote on this issue [here](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/editor-dark-skin-theme-in-free-) to make Unity add it for free users. There might be other ways to do but it's not legal to discus that here. Glad I was able to help and happy coding!