# Scene disappears when zooming in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to start off by saying that I have absolutely no idea how this happened, it started doing this when I started using Unity today and have literally no idea where to start debugging...

So, this below screenshot shows the maximum I can zoom in on computer 1:
[image: Computer 1 max zoom]

If I try and go any further this happens:
[image: Computer 1 exceeding max zoom]

Meanwhile, opening the same project on computer 2, I can zoom in even further than the demonstrated amount...
[image: Computer 2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Update:

It is NOT a duplicate question, clipping plane does not affect the scene window, it is a property of the Camera component and as I clearly show this problem occurs only in the scene tab, not the game tab.

Comment: Really really strange that @Programmer marked this as an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011722/when-i-run-the-game-scene-on-unity-my-panels-dissappears

Comment: @juanitogan It's a disappearing issue which is caused by "clipping plane ". Can you explain why it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @Programmer, I shouldn't have to.  I would just be restating the content of both the questions and the solutions.  This one is about the scene camera in the editor and the other is about the game camera... which don't share the same solution.

Comment: @Programmer  Ingame camera and editor virtual camera are different. Ingame have Inspector, editor one doesn't even exist in runtime. You didn't read the question carefully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try **double clicking** on a canvas *GameObject* in a *Hierarchy*.

A zoom thing happens to me when I work with huge objects. Editor camera adjusts to an editable object. So if you are working with a terrain that is 1000x1000 units, a small house that is 5x5 units will be clipping in closeup, when you will zoom to it manually. Double clicking zooms correctly to an object and adjusts editor camera clip planes.

Hope it is your case. Tell me if it so.

Comment: Yeah, this worked! Thanks!

Comment: I was lucky today. To find your question. It's hard for me to get rep here. I always find answers to my questions in super old posts, so I don't need to ask. Or I figure things while writing the question. Or I just am too late to answer something I can :(
So it was a good birthday present from you. :)

Comment: You can also get rep up by asking questions ;)

Comment: That's the thing. You can look at my questions. Even when I ask something it is when I'm confused, that I can't even formulate it. And I usually want to do something complicated, so nobody will even try answering that or I'll get myself how to do things.

Comment: How to unflag this question? It is not duplicate. This solution won't fit there. Because it is an editor camera bug, but there (link by Programmer) is a game camera thing.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been wondering what changes the zoom limits for a very long time.  My work process never involves intentionally double clicking objects in the hierarchy but I do occasionally accidentally double click them.  Thus, the zoom limits seemed to be changing at random on rare occasion.  (And, yeah, not a duplicate of that other question.)

Comment: Yeagh. That was annoying me until I figured this out.

Comment: Still relevant in Unity 2019.4.10f1

Comment: And it is still marked as duplicate